New service failing on .gif uploads
I'm having trouble uploading .gifs (generated by the Peek screen-recorder) using the recently introduced image service, via the provided tool. I'm getting consistent failutre, with: 'An error occured, please try again'.
Chrome browser, Linux, .gif readable by browser as a direct upload.
Can anyone reproduce this behaviour?

Tested just now and I successfully uploaded a GIF fine from Firefox under Windows. Now that you mentioned it, I do recall encountering a similar issue some days back. I though it was some temporary outage, and eventually went away; but if it's happening again, then maybe it is a symptom of something else wrong with the service. May be a regional thing that only affects certain parts of the content distribution network

Thanks,  @Duarte  for having a look, I'll check again after a decent interval .. I've not had any success so far in a couple of  days.

Ouch that is a long time to wait though, especially if you meant to post some critical answer. When I mentioned waiting it out I was imagining a few hours long outage tops, not several days. If I recall correctly for me it was a matter of minutes maybe. Maybe report it to the CMs then, maybe they are not aware of the issues; or perhaps these are just expected outages caused by overload during the migration process. In the meantime maybe you can work around it by manually uploading to imgur if it is an urgent matter.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I've posted here .. assuming that gets through.

Related on Meta SE: adding gifs or images is very laggy or provides errors

@AndrewT. Thanks for the link

@RobinBetts: i have the exact same problem :(.  Uploading images now takes significant longer or fails. Gifs only upload 1 out of 20 tries. So it's getting worse. I just hope it will be better once the new system is "ready installed"

Hi, @Chris thanks for your post to the Big Meta :)  Bit of a mystery to me why bad for some and not for others, suggests variations in .gif format matters?.. but I would have thought that was an encapsulated concern... and even then why does it sometimes work ...

i can just assume - but i might be because they are transferring now the "old" images to a new server and it is just "too much" for the server. But that's just an assumption.

@RobinBetts another user mentioned some workarounds in the meantime. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398974/uploading-a-gif-doesnt-work-on-some-se-sites/

Marking [status-completed] per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398974/uploading-a-gif-doesnt-work-on-some-se-sites/

Thanks for rounding this out, @Slate. Appreciated.
