How to solve the issue of most images on Blender Stack Exchange being blocked for my IP?
Recently, I can no longer see any images on Stack Exchange sites:

These show up everywhere all the time and when I try to go to the image's URL manually, I get

oh no, that request didn't look right RayID: [some random ID]


from https://i.sstatic.net/[some_image_name.png] addresses. I found out that it has something to do with Cloudfare protection. I can access the images using a web proxy manually copying their addresses. Also when I access the page from another device logged on to my account and connected to a mobile network from another internet provider, it works and then the images also get fixed for that page if I refresh it from my regular home internet.
So I assume that this is some security measure failing me badly, but not seeing images on Blender Stack exchange is a huge problem for me if I want to keep using it, which I would really prefer... Internet searches indicate that I might not be alone experiencing similar issues. There seem to be other Stack Exchange users experiencing this as well... How can this be solved or even where would one start? Who would I need to seek support from?
Same issue here:
Images from i.sstatic.net only work for me after being accessed from another IP address

Issue persists with all devices connected to my home network in case someone might be wondering. So I really think there is a problem on Stack Exchange end...

It seems Stack exchange contract with Imgur has terminated, and they have begun a process of transitioning to self hosting all the stack exchange images themselves. This is probably one of the many issues users have been experiencing issue caused by the new service and the ongoing transitioning process. See https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/new-service-failing-on-gif-uploads

Are you perhaps accessing  from some a corporate network or using a shared web access? Some times many users sharing the same outbound  IP address may inadvertently look like a coordinate attack trigger cloudfare DOS protection

No, it's standard home internet plan. One computer connecting to the internet and sharing it to 2 other wifi devices. Nothing too suspicious about my activity online I can think of... I have used ad blocking DNS, but it doesn't seem to work with Google DNS either. I'll try my internet provider's default DNS just in case. Maybe it got blocked because of that... But why should it?.. And why does it fix itself in such weird circumstances?..

Seems to be a really bad situation for me. Not a lot of people may be experiencing this bug so it's likelihood to be solved soon does not to seem to be great. :( I cannot use BSE like that... :( It's really sad situation...

We will escalate the issue and try to report it to the CMs. This may well be just a temporary problem, during the transition process while the servers are probably busier than usual. I'm sure it will get sorted out when the dust settles. We will let you know if we get a response

is this still an issue currently? Has it been resolved in the meantime?

Still an issue. I just don't see images on Stack Exchange sites anymore. Was anything done about it?

I've tagged it as a bug so that developers take a look at it. I've also notified in chat, hopefully this time it goes through

Sorry this is taking so long, it is on the current bugs list, the devs are looking into it. Hopefully it won't take much longer

@Martynas May I ask, is it possible you are behind a proxy or an ISP that is modifying the requests your device sends? It is most likely that this is triggering hotlink protection, which is designed to prevent people from loading Stack Exchange images on non-Stack Exchange sites. If your device or ISP are editing the requests your device sends, it could result in the images failing to load

Actually, I use web proxy to view the images. I use different DNS servers than my ISP provides, but other than that, I cannot think of anything.

@Slate, I am not sure I understand what you mean, actually. In what cases and how would an ISP or device modify requests? I use my PC as a wifi hotspot to connect other devices that then also experience this problem so it might be related to one device. I'll try to boot from another OS to see if that changes anything.

Just to be clear - I have never experienced this problem during 5+ years I use this internet provider and I don't experience it on any other sites, just all Stack Exchange sites, which is weird, because I am sure I must have encountered at least some other sites using hotlink protection, right?

@Martynas To be honest, I don't know if you'd have run into it. I'm just not sure how common utilization of this feature is, or how often the configuration you'd have run into matches ours. Let me know if you try out a couple other ways and see any success.

@Slate Problem persist when booted from fresh Ubuntu USB stick, so it cannot be my device. I don't even have a router, the PC connects directly to the box provided by my ISP that connects to optic fiber cable - don't know how all that works to be honest.

Is there a way to test if my ISP modifies requests? It's a very standard ISP, most popular one in my country(Lithuania). Standard most popular plan... No idea, what to do. Any advice?..

@MartynasŽiemys Not sure what next steps are personally - I can follow up and ask, however. Could I ask you for a couple more recent Ray IDs?

Of course. 88359b951a9d7120, 88359c10c8187120, 88359c8ed9427120, 88359d3e1ca57120, 88359db57ebc7120 - these are from BSE, but other sites don't work as well. Stack Overflow for example: 8835a01cbc5e7120, 8835a16fabc07120... Old posts from a couple of years back work fine, also the mentioned thing with accessing the page from another ISP still fixes the issue everywhere.

I have to be logged on though. So if I access the page from my phone where I am logged on, it will work. I don't log on through free web proxy sites, because well, I suspect there are reasons they are free. But I can view images using web proxy sites.

Maybe a stupid question, but may I ask which browser you are using (and which version of it)?

I have tried Chrome and Firefox, as well as their mobile versions, all latest versions from Windows, Android and Ubuntu. PC, phone and a tablet. It doesn't seem to be on my end. It seems to be a problem with Stack Exchange maybe because of some configuration my ISP uses. I mean I don't know, maybe it's just my PC, because all internet connections go through it and maybe the IP got blacklisted somehow, but no idea why. I use ad blocking DNS, that's probably the most likely thing... I obviously tired 2 other DNS providers including the one my ISP provides.

It's a problem with Stack Exchange. It seems to affect me and one other user only. As far as they are concerned anyway. So... I sort of understand it might not be worth the effort. I think it might be that this will not get resolved at all... :(

Did this ever get resolved for you? I have the exact same issue, on two different devices (iOS/macOS), different browsers and even different networks (home network/5G) . Unable to see any images on any Stack Exchange website since a few months back.

No. It did not. They forgot about it and I just don't see images any more. It has lead to problems when people delete the alternative text and I am not even aware images exist at all in a few cases :D. I almost voted to close a few questions. I just use web proxy to view the images if some question seems interesting for me to consider answering it. (If I don't feel too lazy to do that). Very nice support system here. They don't know what it is so it doesn't matter. I mean we are just a few users. Who cares?..

I don't mean BSE mods of course they are just users like us, some Stack Overflow staff looked into it. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399031/images-from-i-sstatic-net-only-work-for-me-after-being-accessed-from-another-ip

I think some certain Cloudflare servers that happen to serve a few unlucky people like us get stuck somehow. So it's not even a problem Stack Overflow can solve directly themselves, because they just use Cloudflare's services for protection against attacks the way I understand it which makes it very unlikely this will get fixed. I lost hope completely.
